# Google Sheets Script, automatically casting datatypes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, type-conversion

I'm just testing my own summation function but instead of adding numbers together it seems to be concatenating them as string. In Google Sheets I'm sending the values from column A (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Instead of returning 15, I get 12345

```
sum(testSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues());

function sum(inValues) {
  var runningSum = new Number(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < inValues.length; i++) {
    runningSum += inValues[i];
  }
  return runningSum;
}
```

I started debugging and in the first loop cycle runningSum appears to have instantiated correctly and is a Number, but in every subsequent cycle runningSum seems to have somehow auto-cast itself to a String.

1. Does anyone know how to keep this variable as a Number?
2. In addition is there a way to force strict data types in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make sure the value you read in the SS is interpreted as a number using `Number()`

```
function test(){
  Logger.log(sum(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A:A').getValues()));
}
function sum(inValues) {
  var runningSum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inValues.length; i++) {
    runningSum += Number(inValues[i]);
  }
  return runningSum;
}
```